# Selenium with headless chrome, window.chrome is undefined

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, google-chrome

I'm running selenium tests against a web that only support Chrome and Firefox. If you are using another browser, you can't do nothing.

This is how the frontend check the browser.

```
  var isChrome = !!this.$window.chrome && !!this.$window.chrome.webstore;
  var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
  if(!isChrome && !isFirefox) {
    this.toastservice.error(<browser not supported code>);
  }
```

The problem is that with chrome headless $window.chrome hasn't value and obviosly the frontend not detect it as chrome. Any idea how to surpass this?

And I start webdriver this way:

```
public WebDriver getWebDriver() {
    ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().version("2.37").setup();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

    if (BROWSER.equals("HEADLESS_CHROME")){
        options.setHeadless(true);
        options.addArguments("window-size=1920,1080");
        options.addArguments("hide-scrollbars");            
    }       
    webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    return webDriver;
}
```

If the solution if from the frontend side it would be ok too.

Comment: what if you inject it after initializing webDriver: `((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("this.$window.chrome = {};");` or something like that?

Comment: No, sadly it doesn't work.

Comment: what's weird is `this.$window.chrome`: usually it's `window.chrome`. So who is `this`? where is it constructed? if you figure that out, you may see how to fool it

Comment: I don't know about that, I'll ask front end team about it. Anyway, we solve this detecting headless chrome in our testing environment with this: https://antoinevastel.com/bot%20detection/2018/01/17/detect-chrome-headless-v2.html